# How do I automatically post my Tumblr posts to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, tumblr

How do I automatically post or publish my Tumblr posts to my Facebook page? I don't mean the News Feed one, but a Facebook page.

Answer (score 2):

The staff answers your question here:

http://staff.tumblr.com/post/165847841/facebook

The simple answer:

Go to this link -- http://apps.facebook.com/tumblr-feed/ to activate it

Comment: I've tried it, but FB says: Sorry, the application you were using is misconfigured. Please try again later. is there a alternative for me?
thnx!
Gggg

Comment: It doesn't work for me either: `ERROR: Sorry, the application you were using is misconfigured. Please try again later.`

Answer (score 1):

If the default Tumblr one isn't working you can try a third party.

I've used [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com/)

Find the "recipe" or make your own: if Tumblr then Facebook